# How can I report an error if a dictionary contains duplicates?

Tags: python

My code is something like:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for prod_no ,production in enumerate(productions):
    cp = Production(*productions[prod_no])
    count_yields = len(cp.pattern_list())
    #temp.setdefault(temp[cp.lhs()], []).append(count_yields)
    d[cp.lhs()].append(count_yields)

print d
```

As an output I am getting something like given below:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [3, 3, 4, 3], 'S': [1], 'B': [4,5]})
```

Now I need  to report an error because key 'A' has different multiple values like 3 and 4. Same can be said about key 'B'.

There should not be any error if I am getting an output like

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [3, 3, 3, 3], 'S': [1]})
```

because both 'A' and 'S' has same values throughout...

Comment: Your question is un-clear can you provide more description?

Comment: What behaviour do you want? What behaviour do you actually get? Show the actual statements, if possible.

Comment: {'A':[4,3,3,3], 'S':[1], 'B':[1,2]} As key A contains '3' and '4' so I have to report an error which means I have to ensure that it has either '3' or '4'. if both the values are present then the error should be reported otherwise no error. Moreover this should be ensure for every key in the dictionary.

Comment: I might suggest it would be easier to find these errors when you're constructing the dictionary rather than in a separate pass afterward. If all the items must be identical, you won't even need to store any of the items if you catch the non-matching values at the point they're added.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for duplicates in a list(acc. to the title), you could convert it into a set and check for its length (in this case, 1):

```
if not all(len(set(items))==1 for items in d.values()):
    #A list against some key does not have all-same elements.
```

Comment: It's bad practice to handle errors by `print`ing (and this makes this answer only run on Python 2). Also, you can use De Morgan's theorem to  simplify the condition.

Comment: @phihag You are correct about `print`ing the errors rather than raising it. I have removed that. About the second part, I consider `(A & B)` to be similar to (and not the simplified form of) `(~A | ~B)` although it might seem so when written down. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set) instead of lists as the value of your dictionary if you don't want duplicate values. In any case, you can check for duplicate values with

```
dct = {'A': [4,3,3,3], 'S': [1]}
if any(len(v) != len(set(v)) for v in dct.values()):
   raise ValueError('Duplicate values in an item list')
```

Answer (score 0):

if d is the dictionary (it can be any dictionary including the default dictionary). You can use the following code. This will check for repetitions in the dictionary

```
for i in d.values():
    if len(set(i)) != len(i):
            print str(i) + " error"
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite make out the Python syntax in your example, so I'll answer you based on two different ideas.

What you want to do depends on when you want to do it. For example, if you want to prevent a duplicate value, then here is one way to do that:

```
x_set = {'A':[4, 3]}
incoming_val = 3
if incoming_val in x_set['A']:
  print("The incoming value already present.")
```

If you want to eliminated duplicate values after error reporting, you could do the following:

```
>>> x_set
{'A': [4, 3, 3]}
>>> list(set(x_set['A']))
[3, 4]
>>>
```

You could also put the list append attempt in a try .. catch and signal an exception and catch it. That is also a Pythonic thing to do.

Comment: d = defaultdict(list)
         for prod_no ,production in enumerate(productions):
            cp = Production(*productions[prod_no])
            count_yields = len(cp.pattern_list())
            d[cp.lhs()].append(count_yields)
print d.values()
         print d

Comment: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [3, 3, 3, 3], 'S': [1]})